# Extract Data as per Date Logic in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract the data from Oracle DB and this is the business requirement:

1. On Sunday and Monday, need to extract data as of previous Thursday
2. From Tuesday to Saturday, need to extract data as of (Date column -2)

Need assistance on where clause logic.

Comment: Please provide your current code and describe what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
select *
from your_table
where date_column = 
  case when to_char(sysdate, 'dy') in ('sun', 'mon') then next_day(trunc(sysdate) - 7, 'thu')
       else trunc(sysdate) - 2
  end;
```